# "on click" on entire row/column runs the same macro on all cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a problem with a macro running "on click" on certain column.

I want to code a "check" when clicking on a cell and "check all" on clicking on first row of that row.

[image]

When clicking on an empty cell on column "A", it becomes ✔, and clicking on a cell with ✔, it becomes empty.

And if you click on the Header of that column, all cells become ✔ or empty.

My problem comes when selecting entire row or column. All cells in selection become ✔ or X. Even if the cells are not in the column "A" and even blocking Excel.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    ''Check One
    If Target.Row > 1 Then
        If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) = "" Then End
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
            Cells(Target.Row, 2).Select
        Else
            If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) = "" Then End
            Target.Value = ""
            Cells(Target.Row, 2).Select
        End If
    Else
    ''Check All
        If Target.Value = ChrW(&H2714) Then
            Target.Value = ChrW(&H2716)
            lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To lastRow
                Cells(i, 1) = ChrW(&H2713)
            Next
            Cells(1, 2).Select
            End
        Else
            Target.Value = ChrW(&H2714)
            lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To lastRow
                Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).ClearContents
            Next
            Cells(1, 2).Select
            End
        End If
    End If
End If
End sub
```

I'm not sure what happens, I have other "on click" events that doesn't affect when selecting entire row or column.

Any idea on what's wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You need something like `Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("A"))`  then check `rng` is not Nothing before continuing with `rng` in place of `Target` (since Target may also include cells not in ColA)

Comment: ...or just Exit the sub if `Target.Cells.Count > 1`  FYI you should really use `Exit Sub` in place of just `End`  Use of `End` will clear any global variables you might have elsewhere, so it's a bit of a sledgehammer method to exit your code...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Target.Cells.Count worked.